Sketching periodic orbit and getting the subspaces
Question a) I tried to sketch the periodic orbit but was not very successful. I am not sure how to exactly visualize this. I am not convinced yet but after reading more $\gamma(t)$ is an ellipse in the $(x, y)$ plane; $W^u(\Gamma)$ is a vertical elliptical cylinder through $\gamma(t)$ and $W^s(\Gamma)$ is the $x, y$ plane without the origin and $W^c(\Gamma)$. If I wanted to show or verify that the vertical elliptical cylinder through gamma is an attracting set for the system, what arguments should suffice?
b) I am not sure of the process of finding the stable, unstable and centre subspaces of gamma at a generic point here
The nonlinear system:
\begin{align*}
\dot{x} &= x - 4y - \frac{x^3}{4} - xy^2 \\
\dot{y} &= x + y - \frac{x^2 y}{4} - y^3 \\
\dot{z} &= z.
\end{align*}
There is a $(2 cos 2t, sin 2 t, 0)^T$ periodic solution of this system of period $(T = \pi)$ or the periodic orbit.
The fundamental matrix is $\Phi(t)$ = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{-2t} \cos 2t & -2 \sin 2t & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} e^{-2t} \sin 2t & \cos 2t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^t
\end{bmatrix}.
This satisfies $\Phi(0)= I$. For this system, I found that $(\Phi(t) = Q(t) e^{Bt})$ with $ B = \text{diag}[-2, 0, 1]$ and
Periodic matrix or Q(t) = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos 2t & -2 \sin 2t & 0 \\ 
\frac{1}{2} \sin 2t & \cos 2t & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.
The characteristic exponents of $\gamma(t)$ are $\lambda_1 = -2$ and $\lambda_2 = 1$, and the characteristic multipliers are $\exp(-2\pi) $ and $\exp(\pi)$; $ \dim S(\Gamma) = \dim U(\Gamma) = 2$ and $\dim C(\Gamma) = 1 $.

I think you can decouple the z' equation and focus on the  2×2 subsystem in the  x-y plane

@Moo I think I have sort of figured out how to visualize gamma here but I am still not sure of the process of finding fgamma's stable, unstable and centre subspaces
